# No suitable driver found for jdbc:pstgresql://localhost:5432/hibernatedb

Tags: postgresql, hibernate

I am getting this error. Tried two jar files into src folder, project folder etc too. Please check and help.

Tried Hibernate 3.6.4 and 5.4.2 both in different projects.

```
294 [main] INFO org.hibernate.cfg.Environment - Hibernate 3.6.4.Final
297 [main] INFO org.hibernate.cfg.Environment - hibernate.properties not found
303 [main] INFO org.hibernate.cfg.Environment - Bytecode provider name : javassist
311 [main] INFO org.hibernate.cfg.Environment - using JDK 1.4 java.sql.Timestamp handling
446 [main] INFO org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration - configuring from resource: /hibernate.cfg.xml
446 [main] INFO org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration - Configuration resource: /hibernate.cfg.xml
1330 [main] INFO org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration - Configured SessionFactory: null
1476 [main] INFO org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationBinder - Binding entity from annotated class: org.SecondHibernateProject.dto.UserDetails
1550 [main] INFO org.hibernate.cfg.annotations.EntityBinder - Bind entity org.SecondHibernateProject.dto.UserDetails on table UserDetails
1629 [main] INFO org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration - Hibernate Validator not found: ignoring
1635 [main] INFO org.hibernate.cfg.search.HibernateSearchEventListenerRegister - Unable to find org.hibernate.search.event.FullTextIndexEventListener on the classpath. Hibernate Search is not enabled.
1647 [main] INFO org.hibernate.connection.DriverManagerConnectionProvider - Using Hibernate built-in connection pool (not for production use!)
1647 [main] INFO org.hibernate.connection.DriverManagerConnectionProvider - Hibernate connection pool size: 1
1647 [main] INFO org.hibernate.connection.DriverManagerConnectionProvider - autocommit mode: false
1678 [main] INFO org.hibernate.connection.DriverManagerConnectionProvider - using driver: org.postgresql.Driver at URL: jdbc:pstgresql://localhost:5432/hibernatedb
1678 [main] INFO org.hibernate.connection.DriverManagerConnectionProvider - connection properties: {user=admin, password=****}
1680 [main] WARN org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory - Could not obtain connection to query metadata
java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:pstgresql://localhost:5432/hibernatedb
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
    at org.hibernate.connection.DriverManagerConnectionProvider.getConnection(DriverManagerConnectionProvider.java:133)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory.buildSettings(SettingsFactory.java:113)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSettingsInternal(Configuration.java:2863)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSettings(Configuration.java:2859)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1870)
    at org.vishal.hibernate.HibernateTest2.main(HibernateTest2.java:12)
1742 [main] INFO org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect - Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
1760 [main] INFO org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.JdbcSupportLoader - Disabling contextual LOB creation as connection was null
1762 [main] INFO org.hibernate.transaction.TransactionFactoryFactory - Using default transaction strategy (direct JDBC transactions)
1764 [main] INFO org.hibernate.transaction.TransactionManagerLookupFactory - No TransactionManagerLookup configured (in JTA environment, use of read-write or transactional second-level cache is not recommended)
1764 [main] INFO org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory - Automatic flush during beforeCompletion(): disabled
1764 [main] INFO org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory - Automatic session close at end of transaction: disabled
1765 [main] INFO org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory - Scrollable result sets: disabled
1765 [main] INFO org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory - JDBC3 getGeneratedKeys(): disabled
1765 [main] INFO org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory - Connection release mode: auto
1766 [main] INFO org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory - Default batch fetch size: 1
1767 [main] INFO org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory - Generate SQL with comments: disabled
1767 [main] INFO org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory - Order SQL updates by primary key: disabled
1767 [main] INFO org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory - Order SQL inserts for batching: disabled
1767 [main] INFO org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory - Query translator: org.hibernate.hql.ast.ASTQueryTranslatorFactory
1770 [main] INFO org.hibernate.hql.ast.ASTQueryTranslatorFactory - Using ASTQueryTranslatorFactory
1771 [main] INFO org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory - Query language substitutions: {}
1771 [main] INFO org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory - JPA-QL strict compliance: disabled
1772 [main] INFO org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory - Second-level cache: enabled
1772 [main] INFO org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory - Query cache: disabled
1773 [main] INFO org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory - Cache region factory : org.hibernate.cache.impl.bridge.RegionFactoryCacheProviderBridge
1777 [main] INFO org.hibernate.cache.impl.bridge.RegionFactoryCacheProviderBridge - Cache provider: org.hibernate.cache.NoCacheProvider
1778 [main] INFO org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory - Optimize cache for minimal puts: disabled
1778 [main] INFO org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory - Structured second-level cache entries: disabled
1784 [main] INFO org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory - Echoing all SQL to stdout
1785 [main] INFO org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory - Statistics: disabled
1785 [main] INFO org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory - Deleted entity synthetic identifier rollback: disabled
1786 [main] INFO org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory - Default entity-mode: pojo
1786 [main] INFO org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory - Named query checking : enabled
1786 [main] INFO org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory - Check Nullability in Core (should be disabled when Bean Validation is on): enabled
1868 [main] INFO org.hibernate.impl.SessionFactoryImpl - building session factory
1882 [main] INFO org.hibernate.type.BasicTypeRegistry - Type registration [materialized_blob] overrides previous : org.hibernate.type.MaterializedBlobType@35fc6dc4
2572 [main] INFO org.hibernate.impl.SessionFactoryObjectFactory - Not binding factory to JNDI, no JNDI name configured
2584 [main] INFO org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport - Running hbm2ddl schema export
2585 [main] INFO org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport - exporting generated schema to database
2585 [main] ERROR org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport - schema export unsuccessful
java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:pstgresql://localhost:5432/hibernatedb
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
    at org.hibernate.connection.DriverManagerConnectionProvider.getConnection(DriverManagerConnectionProvider.java:133)
    at org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SuppliedConnectionProviderConnectionHelper.prepare(SuppliedConnectionProviderConnectionHelper.java:51)
    at org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport.execute(SchemaExport.java:263)
    at org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport.create(SchemaExport.java:219)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:372)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1872)
    at org.vishal.hibernate.HibernateTest2.main(HibernateTest2.java:12)
2659 [main] WARN org.hibernate.util.JDBCExceptionReporter - SQL Error: 0, SQLState: 08001
2659 [main] ERROR org.hibernate.util.JDBCExceptionReporter - No suitable driver found for jdbc:pstgresql://localhost:5432/hibernatedb
Exception in thread "main" org.hibernate.exception.JDBCConnectionException: Cannot open connection
    at org.hibernate.exception.SQLStateConverter.convert(SQLStateConverter.java:99)
    at org.hibernate.exception.JDBCExceptionHelper.convert(JDBCExceptionHelper.java:66)
    at org.hibernate.exception.JDBCExceptionHelper.convert(JDBCExceptionHelper.java:52)
    at org.hibernate.jdbc.ConnectionManager.openConnection(ConnectionManager.java:449)
    at org.hibernate.jdbc.ConnectionManager.getConnection(ConnectionManager.java:167)
    at org.hibernate.jdbc.JDBCContext.connection(JDBCContext.java:160)
    at org.hibernate.transaction.JDBCTransaction.begin(JDBCTransaction.java:81)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.beginTransaction(SessionImpl.java:1473)
    at org.vishal.hibernate.HibernateTest2.main(HibernateTest2.java:14)
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:pstgresql://localhost:5432/hibernatedb
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
    at org.hibernate.connection.DriverManagerConnectionProvider.getConnection(DriverManagerConnectionProvider.java:133)
    at org.hibernate.jdbc.ConnectionManager.openConnection(ConnectionManager.java:446)
    ... 5 more
```

My hibernate configuration file looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
        "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
        "http://hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">


<hibernate-configuration>
 <session-factory>
<!--  Database Connection Settings 
  --> 
  <property name="connection.driver_class">org.postgresql.Driver</property> 
  <property name="connection.url">jdbc:pstgresql://localhost:5432/hibernatedb</property> 
  <property name="connection.username">admin</property> 
  <property name="connection.password">admin</property> 

  <!-- JDBC Connection pool (use the build-in) -->
  <property name="connection.pool_size">1</property>

  <!-- SQL dialect --> 
  <property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect</property>

            <!-- Disable Second level cache -->
 <property name="cache.provider_class">org.hibernate.cache.NoCacheProvider</property> 

            <!--  Echo all executed SQL to stdout --> 
  <property name="show_sql">true</property>

            <!--  Drop and re-create the database on startup --> 
  <property name="hbm2ddl.auto">create</property>

  <!--  Names the annotated entity class -->
  <mapping class="org.SecondHibernateProject.dto.UserDetails" /> 
  </session-factory>
  </hibernate-configuration>
```

And the Main Java Class is as below:

```
package org.vishal.hibernate;
import org.SecondHibernateProject.dto.UserDetails;
import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration;;
public class HibernateTest2 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        UserDetails user = new UserDetails();
        user.setUserId(1);
        user.setUserName("First User");
        SessionFactory sessionFactory=new Configuration().configure().buildSessionFactory();
        Session session= sessionFactory.openSession();
        session.beginTransaction();
        session.save(user);
        session.getTransaction().commit();

    }

}
```

Comment: You misspelled "postgresql".

Comment: As uniquemonster wrote: `jdbc:pstgresql` should be `jdbc:postgresql`

Comment: Aah! ..it worked..so silly mistake ..Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Could you please refer the given steps to fix this issue.

1. To download the PostgreSQL jar from the given path as per version.
   https://jdbc.postgresql.org/download.html
2. Add the jar to the project by using "external jar" option in eclipse.
3. Verify the classpath and URL path of PostgreSQL DB.
4. Make sure that the "hibernate.cfg.xml" file should be placed at the root of "src" 
   folder if you are using given code for reading this file.

   ```
   SessionFactory sessionFactory = new Configuration().configure().buildSessionFactory();
   ```
5. If the "hibernate.cfg.xml" located at a different location then read this file from the given path.

   ```
   SessionFactory sessionFactory = new Configuration().configure("/path/to/hibernate.cfg.xml").buildSessionFactory();
   ```